# NRQL query to fetch highest error rate & slowest average response time

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, nrql

[image]

[image]

Attached two images with highest error rate and slowest average response time. I need an NRQL query to find each transaction in the "slowest average response time" and if any one of the transaction is above 3 minutes I need to get an email alert along with transaction name details which is causing the alert.

Required one more NRQL query for "Highest error rate" and if any one of the transaction is above 80% I need to get an email alert along with transaction name details which is causing the alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I need an NRQL query to find each transaction in the "slowest average response time" and if any one of the transaction is above 3 minutes I need to get an email alert along with transaction name details which is causing the alert.`

```
FROM Transaction SELECT count(*) where duration >= 120 facet name
```

Above will give you the count of transactions where duration > 120 seconds, grouped by transaction name. If you set this as an alert, you can set the threshold to >0 to generate incidents any time this occurs.

`Required one more NRQL query for "Highest error rate" and if any one of the transaction is above 80% I need to get an email alert along with transaction name details which is causing the alert`

```
FROM Transaction SELECT percentage(count(*), where error is true or httpResponseCode like '5%' or httpResponseCode like '4%') facet name
```

Above will give the error % per transaction - This can be tweaked to remove specific errors or response codes as well.

Comment: This query looks fine. Is there any way to get past 24 hours transaction report for both (Highest error rate & slowest average response time) every day at 5 PM to email & slack automatically.

Comment: add `since 24 hours ago` to the queries. Add them to a dashboard. View this video for how to send dashboard snapshots to slack or email: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5vBGV2Yy_0

Comment: I can able to send report to slack but only concern in pdf I can able to see only 5 transaction but in dashboard I am having many transaction. Is there any way to get all the dashboard transaction to pdf files

Comment: You could run the nrql query via GraphQL, output to a csv file, and then convert that csv file to a pdf.